# How to randomly choose a function?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

how can I use a variable in your code? I am thinking of writing:

example:
I have a variable x = Math.random (4);

I have a function: timedFunctionb1, timedFunctionb2, timedFunctionb3, timedFunctionb4

Now I want to add X to the function name:

timedFunctionb .....

as there add the variable name to use it when setTimeout (timedFunctionb.x, 5000); it does not work like that. I can not find the correct definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all functions in an array

```
var functions:Array = [timedFunctionb1, timedFunctionb2, timedFunctionb3, timedFunctionb4];
```

Then pick a random element:

```
setTimeout (functions[Math.floor(Math.random() * functions.length)], 5000);
```

Comment: Great idea, but unfortunately write me error: Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 123 1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 0.

Comment: @Martin my bad, I copied the wrong usage of `Math.random()` from your question. I edited my answer.